# SQL - Filter by a relationship

Tags: sql, join, relationship

I have 3 DB table:

```
users: id, name

posts: id, user_id, content

post_likes: id, user_id, post_id
```

I want to fetch my whole user's likes, except likes that I did on my posts. In other words: Fetch all of my likes to other people's posts.

How can I filter by a relationship's column `posts.user_id` when I'm actually fetching `post_likes`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT * FROM post_likes pl
LEFT JOIN posts p ON pl.post_id=p.id
WHERE pl.user_id = 3 AND p.user_id != 3
```

Comment: This should be an inner join. Left join makes no sense here. Moreover as you turn it into an inner join by comparing `p.user_id != 3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this

```
SELECT * FROM post_likes pls 
INNER JOIN posts p ON pls.post_id=p.id
WHERE pls.user_id = 3 AND p.user_id != 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somethin like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
INNER JOIN post_likes pl ON (u.user_id = pl.user_id)
INNER JOIN posts p ON (p.id = pl.post_id AND p.user_id <> u.id)
WHERE u.id = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for post_likes of user 3 where the post_id does not represent a post of his own (i.e. where the post_id is NOT IN the set of his own post_ids):

```
select * 
from post_likes 
where user_id = 3
and post_id not in (select id from posts where user_id = 3);
```